# How to match arbitrary text after a route with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am transition a route from another application that is defined as `/locations/(.*)`.

The other application supports URLs such as `/locations/country=usa&size=large`, rather than your typical query string format of `/locations?country=usa&size=large`.  I'd like to mimic that.

I know that react-router routes are parsed by [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp), which seems to support arbitrary regex in the routes, but my component does not render with the following defined route:

```
<Route path="/locations/(.*)" component={Locations} />
```

What's the correct way to support arbitrary text after a route, rather than your traditional query string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a named query parameter in your route, parsing the query parameter in the locations component and displaying content relevant to the query params.

For example...

```
<Route path="/locations/:locationPath" component={Locations} />
```

and then in the Locations component

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const locationPath = props.match.params.locationPath;
    //    conditionally do something based on locationPath
}
```

You can do this in the constructor, or componentWillMount, componentDidMount or any variation therein. I do mine in the constructor as this is the earliest access to the props object and state.

If you're more certain of the possibility in the query string you can use

```
<Route path="/locations/country=:country,state=:state" component={Locations} />
```

and you will receive country and state as separate keys in the `match.params` object.

Finally, if you don't want to require each param you can use the following

```
<Route path="/locations(/?country:country)(/?state=:state)" component={Locations} />
```

and you will get this route whether state or country is specified alone, or together.

[React Router v4 Route](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md)